# Get a pointer to IUpdate2 interface

Tags: c++, com, window, windows-update

I have the following code snippet,

```
IUpdateSession *iUpdate;
IUpdateSearcher *updateSearcher;
ISearchResult* pISearchResults;
IUpdateCollection* pIUpdateCollection;
IStringCollection *pIStrCollCVEs;
IUpdate2 *pIUpdate;
long lUpdateCount;
```

...

```
CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_UpdateSession,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IUpdateSession,
            (LPVOID*)&iUpdate
            );

iUpdate->CreateUpdateSearcher(&updateSearcher);

printf("\n Searching updates");

updateSearcher->Search(_bstr_t(_T("IsInstalled = 0")), &pISearchResults);
printf("\n Following updates found..\n");

pISearchResults->get_Updates(&pIUpdateCollection);
pIUpdateCollection->get_Count(&lUpdateCount);

LONG lCount;
BSTR buff;
while (0 != lUpdateCount)
{
    pIUpdateCollection->get_Item(lUpdateCount, &pIUpdate);

    pIUpdate->get_CveIDs(&pIStrCollCVEs);

    pIStrCollCVEs->get_Count(&lCount);

    pIUpdate->get_Title(&buff);
    printf("TITLE : %s \n", buff);
    while(0 != lCount)
    {
        pIStrCollCVEs ->get_Item(lCount, &buff);
        _bstr_t b(buff);

        printf("CVEID = %s \n", buff);

        lCount --;
    }

    printf("\n");
    lUpdateCount --;
}


::CoUninitialize();
getchar();
```

ERROR:
error C2664: 'IUpdateCollection::get_Item' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'IUpdate2 * *' to 'IUpdate * *'

@Line43

How to get a pointer to IUpdate2 interface,

Comment: Give it the right type of interface pointer, then query for the one you need afterward. Also, literally *none* of the relevant variables in this question are declared here, making it impossible to eye-check their types. Please post code that makes *sense*. This code also leaks like the Titanic.

Comment: I am willing to use `IUpdate2` interface to use `get_cveIDs()` function..
And about the leaks for COM interfaces,,, its just a try out, not the final code, so m fine with that... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_Item()` member of your collection requires an `IUpdate` interface pointer; not an `IUpdate2` interface pointer.

Note: this code is absolutely **riddled** with bugs, bad practices, and memory leaks. Aong them:

- Interface pointers that are never released
- BSTR's that are never freed.
- HRESULTs that are never checked.
- Invalid indexing into a zero-based collection

Just to name a few. Regardless The following should address your interface mismatch. The rest of this menagerie I leave to you:

```
while (0 != lUpdateCount)
{
    IUpdate* pIUpd = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = pIUpdateCollection->get_Item(lUpdateCount, &pIUpd);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pIUpd)
    {
        hr = pIUpd->QueryInterface(__uuidof(pIUpdate), (LPVOID*)&pIUpdate);
        pIUpd->Release();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pIUpdate != NULL)
        {
            pIUpdate->get_CveIDs(&pIStrCollCVEs);
            pIStrCollCVEs->get_Count(&lCount);

            pIUpdate->get_Title(&buff);
            printf("TITLE : %s \n", buff);
            while(0 != lCount)
            {
                pIStrCollCVEs ->get_Item(lCount, &buff);
                _bstr_t b(buff, false);
                printf("CVEID = %s \n", buff);
                lCount --;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    lUpdateCount--;
}
```

Comment: @51k Its only the most important feature of COM =P. Get a book on COM or spend some time on MS's website reading about it. Its somewhat old-school technology, having been around for about 20 years now, but still worth learning about if you're doing what it looks like you're involved with.